# Why length() piped into an ifelse() does not work properly?

Tags: r, magrittr

```
1:11 %>% length() > 10
```

However, when I pipe it within a `ifelse()`, it evaluates it as if the condition must be applied per each element. Even the output is weird and illogical.

```
1:11 %>% ifelse(length(.) > 10,1)
```

At the same time,

```
ifelse(length(1:11) > 10,1)
```

works properly.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

`magrittr` will always assume that the first argument of a function is `.`, even when not explicit. To drop this assumption:

`1:11 %>% {ifelse(length(.) > 10,1)}`

Comment: `ifelse` is for vectors though, you'd be better off using `if` and `else` in this case